# "not a schema document" when validating XML schema with notepad++ XML tools

Tags: xml, xsd

Im am trying to create an XML schema for the following XML document.
https://www.nationalbanken.dk/_vti_bin/DN/DataService.svc/CurrencyRatesHistoryXML?lang=en

1. As a starting point I have tried to create a very basic XML schema based on the guide from w3 schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp

which as resulted in this - very basic starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" targetNamespace="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:element name="Envelope">

        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

2. Then I have added the gesmes:schemaLocation attribute to the root node of the origional XML document.

```
<gesmes:Envelope 
    xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"
    xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
    gesmes:schemaLocation="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref ..\StockDownloadResources\CurrenciesDownloadMANUAL.XSD">
```

3. Then I have installed installed the XML tools plugin to my Notepad++ and tried to validate the XML doc agains the basic schema.

The validation results in the following error: 
Following error occurred during schema file parsing: The XML document '\CurrenciesDownloadMANUAL.XSD' is not a schema document.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schema document is not valid because the root element needs to have local name `schema` and namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. Your document has a root with local name `schema` and namespace URI `http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01`.

(At a slightly deeper level, the problem is that you are trying to learn from examples, rather than reading something that explains the concepts. W3Schools is like one of those "cheat cards" that gives a one-line summary of the effect of each command, but doesn't take time to explain why the examples work.)

Comment: Thank you for swift response Michael. If you could you point me in direction of a better learning resource than W3schools I would be gratefull.

Comment: There are two good books on XML Schema - Priscilla Walmsley's and Eric van der Vlist's. I find they complement each other so it's useful to have both, but on balance, Priscilla is more readable and Eric is more comprehensive.